# python lxml: если найдено td, то показать другое td

Tags: html, python, lxml

Дана таблица:

```
table='''<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Num of something 1</td>
        <td>4532</td>
        <td>78</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Num of something 2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>235</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Num of something 3</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>6589</td>
    </tr>
</table>'''

if root.xpath('.//td[text()="'+string_parameter+'"]'):
    result = item.xpath('//td[position()=3]')
```

Нужно сделать так: если найден Num of something 3, то вывести 6589

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(table)
print root.xpath("//td[text()='{}']/../td[3]".format("Num of something 3"))[0].text #выведет 6589
```

Python сначала найдет элемент с текстом `Num of something 3`, потом поднимется на уровень выше и оттуда найдет третий элемент  с тегом `td`